# Deploy ruby app on Dokku: why does Bundler config forces "without production"?

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler, gemfile, dokku

Using Dokku 0.5.3, I have an issue deploying a Ruby/Rack app: Bundler doesn't install my gems in `:production` group.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'bundler'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
gem 'json'
gem 'thin'
gem 'instagram'
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'dm-types',
  :git => 'git://github.com/julienma/dm-types.git',
  :branch => 'gem-v1.2.2-with-frozen-nilclass-fix'

gem 'dm-postgres-adapter', :group => :production

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
  gem 'dotenv'
  gem 'pry'
end
```

Here's the output when I push my repo to dokku:

```
Counting objects: 114, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
Writing objects: 100% (114/114), 13.76 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 114 (delta 53), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building my-app from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/julienma/dm-types.git
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
       Installing backports 3.6.8
       Installing addressable 2.4.0
       Installing daemons 1.2.3
       Using json 1.8.3
       Installing fastercsv 1.5.5
       Installing json_pure 1.8.3
       Installing multi_json 1.11.2
       Installing stringex 1.5.1
       Installing uuidtools 2.1.5
       Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing eventmachine 1.2.0.1 with native extensions
       Installing hashie 3.4.3
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Installing tilt 2.0.2
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
       Installing dm-core 1.2.1
       Installing faraday 0.9.2
       Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing faraday_middleware 0.9.2
       Installing dm-aggregates 1.2.0
       Installing dm-constraints 1.2.0
       Installing dm-migrations 1.2.0
       Installing dm-serializer 1.2.2
       Installing dm-transactions 1.2.0
       Using dm-types 1.2.2 from git://github.com/julienma/dm-types.git (at gem-v1.2.2-with-frozen-nilclass-fix@b34937c)
       Installing dm-timestamps 1.2.0
       Installing dm-validations 1.2.0
       Installing sinatra 1.4.7
       Installing instagram 1.1.6
       Installing sinatra-contrib 1.4.6
       Installing data_mapper 1.2.0
       Installing thin 1.6.4 with native extensions
       Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 35 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development, test and production were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (42.90s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

---
       addons: []
       config_vars:
       LANG: en_US.UTF-8
       RACK_ENV: production
       default_process_types:
       rake: bundle exec rake
       console: bundle exec irb
       web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing my-app (dokku/my-app:latest)...
-----> Deploying my-app (dokku/my-app:latest)...
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.predeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/my-app/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file not found in app image. Generating one based on Procfile...
-----> New DOKKU_SCALE file generated
=====> web=1
-----> Running pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/checks-examples.md for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> my-app web container output:
       /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- dm-postgres-adapter (LoadError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core.rb:230:in `setup'
        from /app/controllers/app.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/config.ru:1:in `require'
        from /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
       Using rack adapter
=====> end my-app web container output
To ssh://dokku@my-host.com:22/my-app
 ! [remote rejected] patch-dm-postgres-adapter-deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://dokku@my-host.com:22/my-app'
```

The ruby error is because it can't require `dm-postgres-adapter`, because its gem has not been installed.
Bundler also states that `Gems in the groups development, test and production were not installed.`.

Here's what I know:

- I do have a local `.bundler/config` containing `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production`, but this is `.gitignore`'d.
- On the dokku instance, this is what `dokku run my-app bundle config` gives me:

  ```
  Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
  without
  Set for your local app (/app/.bundle/config): "development:test:production"
  Set via BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test"
  Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "development:test:production"
  ...
  ```

I can understand where the `development:test` of the `without` clause comes from, but I'm really at a lost to understand how and why `production` is also there.

I also tried to set an ENV var `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test` *before* deploying for the 1st time. It's taken into account, however it's preceded by the local bundler config, which already excludes `production`.

---

I solved this by manually editing `/home/dokku/my-app/cache/.bundle/config` and remove `production`:

```
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
```

After pushing again, Bundler successfully installed my `production` gem.

But I don't want to have to manually edit configuration files on the server to get it to work.

So, the QUESTION:

- **Why is `production` group ignored by Bundler when deploying on Dokku?**
- **How can I force my `production` gems to be installed?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use the heroku buildpack, so its possible the latest buildpack has an issue with setting proper defaults?